# Why SVR kernels other than 'linear' don't work for this toy dataset!

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, modeling, python

I'm a little new with modeling techniques and I'm trying to compare SVR and Linear Regression. I've used f(x) = 5x+10 linear function to generate training and test data set. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859831/modeling-support-vector-regression-svr-vs-linear-regression/34860180#34860180) we've discussed why SVR with `rbf` Kernel fails in prediction of such a simple dataset. This is the python code snippet with SVR `linear` kernel that we've tried.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X = np.linspace(0,100,101)
y = np.array([(100*np.random.rand(1)+num) for num in (5*x+10)])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

svr = SVR(kernel='linear')
lm = LinearRegression()
svr.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1),y_train.flatten())
lm.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1), y_train.flatten())

pred_SVR = svr.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))
pred_lm = lm.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))

plt.plot(X,y, label='True data')
plt.plot(X_test[::2], pred_SVR[::2], 'co', label='SVR')
plt.plot(X_test[1::2], pred_lm[1::2], 'mo', label='Linear Reg')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');
plt.show()
```

[image]

Later by changing SVR kernel to `rbf` it fails to provide an acceptable solution. 
[image]

I'm really confused why this happens in case of such a toy dataset!?

Comment: "True data" is a rather strange label. From the text, it seems that the true data generating function should be a straight line--it doesn't even say that random error has been added (although I suspect it has). Is that squiggly line the true function, or this set of realized values? FWIW, if the data are generated linearly, at first blush it makes sense that a linear function will fit better.

Comment: I thought it'd be a parameter tuning issue, except that e1071 in @Fabian's answer seems to be using the same parameters....

Comment: @Dougal: Indeed, just printing out 'model' gives 

`    Call:
    svm.default(x = training_x, y = training_y, type = "eps-regression", kernel = "radial")


Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  1 
    epsilon:  0.1 


Number of Support Vectors:  33
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if this is a Bug/numerical instability in the scikit package (or we/you are using it wrongly although I can't see an obvious mistake...):

As far as I have understood from the documentation, scikit uses libsvm to do the actual optimization magic. Using R and its binding to libSVM (i.e. both approaches should compute exactly the same thing) I get senseful results:

R code:

```
install.packages("e1071")
library("e1071")
x = 1:100
y = 5*x + 10 + 100*runif(n = length(x), min = 0, max = 1)

binomial = sample.int(2, size=100, replace=T)-1
training_x = x[binomial==1]
training_y = y[binomial==1]

test_x = x[binomial==0]
test_y = y[binomial==0]

model = svm(training_x,training_y,kernel="radial",type = "eps-regression")
new = predict(model, test_x)

plot(x, y)
points(test_x, new, col = "red")
```

result: (red points are the ones predicted by SVM):
[image]

I would recommend to write this question to the owners of scikit-learn (including the R code in order to be able to compare).

Regards,

FW

Answer (score 1):

The `SVR` call with the `rbf` kernel should be done while specifying the `C` and `gamma` options:

```
svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
```

Below is the result using the `rbf` kernel:

[image: SVR(RBF) vs linear regression]